# Ordering a Linked List-Structure in a SQL or LINQ Query?

Tags: .net, t-sql

I have a database that essentially looks like this:

```
id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
data nvarchar
nextid uniqueidentifier NULL
```

This is a Linked List, as each nextid links to an id in that table, except for the last one, here nextid is NULL. I do know the id of the first node.

I want to SELECT them all in the correct order, given a start id.

Is there a way this can be done in T-SQL *(Edit: SQL 2008)* or LINQ?

I know I can write code to do it manually in C#, just wondering if I can already query in that order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure of [SortOrder] makes any difference as I don't have enough data to test it. It allows you to sort in both directions.

```
with cteList as
(
    select id, data, nextid, 1 as [SortOrder]
    from #TableTemp
    where id = 'E8ADAA52-54F8-4FE3-BE59-9852E52B33F5' --id of the 1st item

    union all

    select #TableTemp.id, #TableTemp.data, #TableTemp.nextid, (cteList.[SortOrder] + 1) as [SortOrder]
    from #TableTemp
    join cteList on #TableTemp.id = cteList.nextid
)
select * from cteList
order by [SortOrder] asc
```

Comment: This is cool! `(cteList.[SortOrder] + 1)` should be just `([SortOrder] + 1)` though, otherwise SQL complains that the multi-part identifier could not be bound

Comment: Thanks for the comment! For some reasons, it did work for me in mssql 2005 enterprise manager when i wrote the query.

Answer (score 3):

What version of SQL Server?  If it's 2005 or newer you can use a recursive CTE do it.

```
with linked_list as (
  select
    id, data, nextid
  from
    table
  where
    id = @head
  union all
  select
    t.id, t.data, t.nextid
  from
    table t
    join linked_list ll on t.id = ll.nextid
)
select
  *
from
  linked_list
```

Comment: Nice work with the CTE.  Probably would be good to edit to enforce the correct ordering of the result rows since `UNION [ALL]` doesn't guarantee a particular order.

Comment: Interesting, that works. I've changed it to iterate backwards (where id IS NULL, join on ll.id = t.nextid), is there a way to now reverse the result set? (just curious, I can do that in LINQ easily as well)

Comment: @Phil: just wondering, wouldn't the Join guarantee the order? In my test it works fine, but I only have a small test set so far.

Comment: The CTE will be built "in order", however, temp tables don't really have an order so the select * at the end could reorder it (if it wanted).  However, the current version of SQL server won't reorder it (and in fact, MS documentation on recursive CTEs use the union all / join to order the results).  @Eric's solution above me does explicit ordering in case you're worried about potential problems in future versions.

Comment: @Michael - If you want to do it backwards you either need a doubly linked list (since this is basically traversing the list and outputting each item as it gets to it.  Basically.  Kinda.), or use @Eric's solution and change the sort to desc

Comment: @Michael: That's great that it's working for you.  I bring up the ordering issue because without an explicit ORDER BY, the database engine is not required to return your rows in any particular order.

Comment: @Phil @Donnie Yes, I'm using Eric's approach right now with "where nextid IS NULL", join linked_list on ll.id = t.nextid - this gives me the results backwards (and allows me to not need the ID of the head node anymore) and then I sort by Sort Order. I'll test it with larger result sets soon to see how well the UNION ALL works.