# Select top 10 items ordered by "nextid" in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, sorting, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to implement custom ordering of items in a Entity Framework 5 SQL-database.

To implement the custom ordering I have choosen a method with a Item.NextId-property that points to the next item in the ordered list. The first item is the item that no item points to. And last the item that is not pointing to any other item.

The Items-table is basically just: [Id] [NextId]

The tricky part is how I get this ordered list of items out of EF/SQL without doing more then one query. I could get the items unordered and do the ordering myself in .NET or javascript but I'd like to be able to get for instance the first 10 items in this ordered list and then I need to have the correct order before capping the result in the EF-query.

Can somebody point me in a right direction? Can this be solved with a LINQ-query-expression?

Comment: Have you tried to sort with `orderby` in LINQ expression?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. The order is not like ordered int's, It's a completely custom order like: 3, 7, 1, 2, 8, 9, 4 etc where the next id in the order only is available from the previous item. So I need to do some kind of recursive select.

Comment: im not sure if it is possible with efficient linq, but this might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371423/ordering-a-linked-list-structure-in-a-sql-or-linq-query